# Python get the path of the program that has modified the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-monitoring

So I'm trying to monitor file modifications and by who they've been modified by. So far I've written this:

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

but this just detects the modifications and their dates. I couldn't find any solutions to get by who it was modified by.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the difference? Surely all modifications are done  by programs.

Comment: @quamrana You're right. I've edited it.

Comment: What logging outputs do you currently see?

Comment: @quamrana 2022-04-03 hour - Created directory: .\New folder
2022-04-03 hour - Modified directory: .\New folder (slightly modified to clear personal information)

Comment: I'm guessing that the watchdog library has no access to the username of the program involved.

Comment: @quamrana You're probably right but who said that you were limited to only use watchdog?

Comment: I am not aware of any operating system since 1971 that records this information.

Comment: @user207421 I'm not sure about that. Take a look at this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130827-00/?p=3393

Comment: @TheCodeExpert So that's one. How is Python to implement that on all the others that it supports?

Comment: @user207421 That's the question. I don't know how to do it either.